# Why does the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix contain $24$ products?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> $(a)$ If $a_{11}=a_{22}=a_{33}=0$, how many of the $6$ terms in $det A$ will be zero?
>   
> $(b)$ If $a_{11}=a_{22}=a_{33}=a_{44}=0$, how many of the $24$ products $a_{1j}a_{2k}a_{3l}a_{4m}$ are sure to be zero?

My question resolve around question $(b)$. I do not understand where *$24$ products* arise from. I am guessing that it is a $4 \times 4$ matrix (all I can mathematically related is $(16-4) \cdot 2 = 24$)?

Comment: I am guessing that you are supposed to pick one entry from each one of the for rows of $\mathbf{A}$, but also exactly one from each column. That is, if you pick the second entry of the first row, then you cannot pick the second entry in rows 2, 3 and 4, etc.

Comment: Please clarify the question yourself by giving the context and not just a little scrap of the original exercise!

Comment: @KarlMorrison I've edited your question and added $\LaTeX$. [and no one is stopping me from editing](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=month), It's just that OP's(original poster) efforts towards posting well formatted questions will save time and efforts of editors. Next time I expect a nicely formatted question from your side. Good Luck! Have Fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the number of products in the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix is $n!$ (so in this case, we have $4! = 24$ terms). This can be seen by applying an induction argument to a cofactor expansion. Indeed, the number of terms when cofactor expanding along a row is $n$ times the number of terms in the determinant of a matrix of size $(n - 1) \times (n - 1)$.

Comment: Thank you! Others should take your lead and explain mathematics to people which do not have mathematics as their major!